# How can you get an external swf to load and slide down from another swf like a sliding pencil ad in ActionScripting 2.0

Tags: flash

I have two SWFs, one is a 960x30px, the other is a 960x300px. I can get it to load the 960x300 from the 960x30, but I can't get it to load by sliding down underneath it, keeping it 960x300. I have written external JavaScript to move the content underneath down. It needs to be in Actionscripting 2.0 There is one correct example on my web site for Penn State with the girl. www.heraldstandard.com Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which comes immediately to mind is to have the second SWF spawn from a javascript function, and call said function from within Flash using getURL.

So, say:

```
<script language="javascript">
function SpawnSecondSWF() {
alert("Replace this alert with the code to inject an SWF into your page's DOM");
}
</script>
```

Then, within flash, you can call `getURL("javascript:SpawnSecondSWF();");`

Comment: Thank you Jordaan, I'll give it a try.